# How do I iterate ManyToMany field in Django template tag?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have an object that contains a Many-to-Many field. I'm trying to iterate this field in Django template, but apparently I can't. Let me show you the code first.

models.py:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100, blank=True)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

views.py:

```
def book_list(request):
    books = Book.objects.all().order_by('-pk')
        
    context = {
        'books' : books,
    }
    return render(request, 'contents/book_list.html', context)
```

Template file:

```
{% for b in books %}
<div>
    {{b.title}}
    {% for cat in b.category %}
    {{cat}}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Now I get `'ManyRelatedManager' object is not iterable` error. How do I iterate the field and show all the `category` in each object?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because if you call `b.category` it returns only the relation object. To get its values (`category` objects) you have to add `.all`. Like this:

```
{% for b in books %}
<div>
    {{ b.title }}
    {% for cat in b.category.all %}
        {{cat}}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

By the way, I've also changed `c.title` to `b.title`, because I assume you want this book title, not something from global.